# Shell script replace variable with another variable have content & character by using sed

Tags: shell, sed

Here is the example:

```
v="1 & 2"

x="3 & 4"

echo $v | sed "s/$v/$x/"

3 1 & 2 4 <------result not replaced by 3 & 4
```

I want to replace `1 & 2` to `3 & 4`, but seem the result given not the one I needs.
Anyone can help to fix my problem?

Comment: I think i found the solution, add \ in x="3 \& 4", then I can obtain the result I wish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` in the replacement text is a metacharacter that means 'what was matched on the LHS of the `s///` operation'.

You'll need to escape the `&` with a backslash.

```
v="1 & 2"
x="3 & 4"
y=$(echo "$x" | sed 's/&/\\\&/g')
echo "$y"
echo "$v" | sed "s/$v/$y/"
```

Output:

```
3 \& 4
3 & 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` `&` has a special meaning. It contains the entire match from the substitution part. When your replacement variable is expanded `sed` sees it as `3 & 4` where `&` contains `1 & 2`. Hence you get `3 1 & 2 4` in the output.

You can escape the `&` to make it work.

```
$ v="1 & 2"
$ x="3 \& 4"
$ echo $v | sed "s/$v/$x/"
3 & 4
```